# Is there a java library equivalent to file command in unix

Tags: java, unix, file, content-type

Is there any java library that is similar to unix's command `file`?

ie:

```
$ file somepicture.png
somepicture.png PNG image, 805 x 292, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

The file command is such a nice tool. I need something that can tell me if the file is really what I want it to be. (ie a picture, document etc)

I know I can run the command `file`, but I am looking for a java library, not running the actual unix command.

Comment: I ended up using Apache Tika. JMimeMagic was poorly documented. (Not that Tika was better, but the API was easier IMO)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quick google search (for the admittedly non-obvious)  ["java magic file detection"](http://www.google.co.il/search?hl=en&qscrl=1&q=java+magic+file+detection&meta=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) brings up a fairly nice looking article, ["Get the Mime Type from a File"](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) which suggests you use one of the following:

- [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)
- [JMimeMagic](https://github.com/arimus/jmimemagic)

Comment: Thanks.
I think one of these two should do the trick. Its really documents and images I need.

Answer (score 11):

Since Java 1.7 you can use [Files.probeContentType()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path)) to probe a file. Out of box it uses the mechanism on the platform to guess the content type, or you can plugin your own detector if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [jmimemagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) ([tutorial](http://marvinlee.wordpress.com/2007/10/24/check-uploaded-file-mime-type-with-jmimemagic/)). We've been using it for a while to validate uploaded images. No problems so far.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it is exactly what you are looking for, but the following link can maybe help you :

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html

Comment: +1 for giving the JDK-only solution.  I'm not sure how good that method is, but it could be what the user is looking for.

Comment: @bkail `javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap` only checks the file extension which surely isn't a reliable way of determining "if the file is really what I want it to be"

Comment: Yes the JDK solution is not working like `file` in unix. `file` really looks at the file and tells what it is. Doesn't care about extension like windows does

Comment: @sfussenegger java.net.URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(InputStream) surely does not use file extensions to make its determination.

Comment: @bkail That wasn't mentioned in the linked article, was it? Anyway, it's not working reliably. I've just tried and it failed for a simple jpg image.

Comment: @sfussenegger Huh, I thought getContent/getContentType used guessContentTypeFromStream.  Ah, apparently only for "jar:" URLs.  Thanks for the clarification...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [mime-utils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/).
It works with content and/or with extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in the JDK is `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream`

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same thing and found this: https://github.com/j256/simplemagic - it seems to be a clone of 'file', it even uses a copy of files built-in magic file.