# how to set res.setContentType("application/xls") dynamic in spring while downloading the file

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, download

I want to download a file which is available in the server itself

`AppName\resources\attachemnts\file.extension(this can be anything)` i have got the code from the net the following is the same.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileDownload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void handleFileDownload(@RequestParam("fileLocation") String fileLocation,HttpServletResponse res) {
            try {

                URL url = getClass().getResource(fileLocation);
                File f = new File(url.toURI());
                System.out.println("Loading file "+fileLocation+"("+f.getAbsolutePath()+")");
                if (f.exists()) {
                    res.setContentType("application/xls");
                    res.setContentLength(new Long(f.length()).intValue());
                    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.xls");
                    FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(f), res.getOutputStream());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File"+fileLocation+"("+f.getAbsolutePath()+") does not exist");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

i have to set `res.setContentType("application/xls");` dynamic since the file type is going to be different each time.

How to get file type?

Comment: Hi @Balu C what was the reason for deleting your post :). I was helpful to some extend also hope you are the one who down voted for my post, Great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For determining type of file, you may use any library which checks [file's magick numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) and returns its filetype. For example:

- [jMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/).
- [mime-util](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/)
- [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)

See also related questions:

- [Identifying file type in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583463/identifying-file-type-in-java)
- [Is there a java library equivalent to file command in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729038/is-there-a-java-library-equivalent-to-file-command-in-unix)