# Having a byte array, how to know the image type?

Tags: java, image

I have this :

```
byte[] image;
```

How to get the format of the image format?

Comment: You've you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040330/how-to-extract-file-extension-from-byte-array

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583463/identifying-file-type-in-java

Comment: Here is nice example for your scenario with java. http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/how-to-find-a-files-image-type-by-looking-at-its-bytes-in-java/

Comment: I see that Mime type method is related to the HTTP server. For me this is in desktop.