# Identify extension of a file based on its stem name

Tags: java, file

I have a simple problem that I am quite struggling with. I have several files in a directory and I am reading them and passing processing them based on their type (extension). However, as an input, I receive a path to the file without extension so I have to identify the type myself.

example (files):

```
files/file1.txt
files/file1.txt
files/pic1.jpg
----------------
String path = "files/file1";
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(path); // this returns null
```

Is there a way to identify the type of file when the extension is not included in the path?

Comment: You can check the MIMEType of file

Comment: MIMEtype or [This](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) `getExtension`

Comment: @A_N_Y_R the OP already appears to be using that class...

Comment: I would suggest using  [`Files.probeContentType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-) to try and deduce the mime type. But there is no 100% reliable way of knowing what a file is except trying to read it as something and seeing if there are issues.

Comment: Ahhh yes. Just stated what I remembers.

Comment: If it's not already in `path`, how is `ext` going to get it? So my question is, how are you getting the filenames, and why is that thing dropping extensions? No point in using something which drops them, and then trying to get it back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729038/is-there-a-java-library-equivalent-to-file-command-in-unix

Comment: @A_N_Y_R I really wish people would stop suggesting the ancient and **obsolete** Apache libraries. Commons IO 2.4 [was released in 2012](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4).

Comment: And what if there are two files with the same base-name and two different extensions?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have tested this API; and the problem is that it wrongly relies on file extensions. It will, for instance, detect a PNG image named "foo.txt" as `text/plain`. `FileTypeDetector`s is really your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only given part of the file name, you'll need to search for files that start with that prefix. Note that there could be multiple matches.

**Using java.nio.file**

```
Path prefix    = Paths.get(path);
Path directory = prefix.getParent();

try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(directory)) {
    stream.filter(p -> p.getFileName().startsWith(prefix.getFileName() + "."))
          .forEach(p -> System.out.printf("Found %s%n", p));
}
```

**Using java.io**

```
File       prefix    = new File(path);
File       directory = prefix.getParentFile();
List<File> matches   = directory.listFiles((dir, name) ->
                           name.startsWith(prefix.getName() + "."));

for (File match: matches) {
    System.out.printf("Found %s%n", match);
}
```

Comment: Why use java.io.File in 2015 at all?

Comment: Perhaps my knowledge is out of date. Is `java.io.File` officially or unofficially deprecated these days?

Comment: It's not deprecated, and in fact many libraries and APIs still require you to use it to some extent or another. @fge is just campaigning that we stop teaching it to Java newcomers so that it can begin to be phased out.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet here is to "do it yourself" by implementing instances of [`FileTypeDetector`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html).

When you have this, you can then just use [`Files.probeContentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-) to have a string returned which describes the file contents as a MIME type.

---

The JDK does provide a default implementation but it relies on file extensions, basically; if you have a PNG image named `foo.txt`, the default implementation will return `text/plain` where the file is really an `image/png`.

Which is of course wrong.

---

Final note: if all you really have is only part of the file name, then use  `Files.newDirectoryStream()` and provide it with the appropriate `DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>`. Not sure yet why you only have *part* of it though.

Comment: Is there an example of such approach somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there aren't. I intended to try that out, but basically you need a file in `META-INF/services` named `java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector` where all your implementations are listed. Those will then be registered by the JVM.

Comment: Sad. But true. This _is_ the only truly robust way.

Comment: @BoristheSpider on the other hand writing such a detector might be made easier should there exist a Java library equivalent to libmagic; personally I haven't dug in that direction though.

Answer (score 0):

`Files.probeContentType(Path)` implements a basic MIME type inquiry you can use (or extend), the internal details of which are platform specific. You can also make a little utility method that walks a Set of extensions. A combination of the two approaches may be necessary, depending on your application.

The MIME type checker will give different results on different releases  implementations of the JRE. So, always have a fail-over solution.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path

[EDIT]

This actually does not answer the question posited, as this method needs a full, legal `Path` object to work on. If you are given just the stem name, and the extension is missing, then you neither have an extension to work with nor a valid `Path` name for `Files` to work with [and probeContentType() may, in some implementations, just use the extension anyway.]

I'm not sure how you can do this without Path that refers to a real on-disk file that the JRE can access, or by hand if you don't have an extension. If you don't have a File of some sort, you can't even open it up yourself to attempt file type "magic".